# I used Windows Authentication on SQL Server and now I reinstalled new Windows, and cannot access my database(mdf files)

Tags: sql-server

What should I do? I could disable UAC to access the database. Is there a way I could copy the my database but strip the account control informations attached to it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/07/12/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005.aspx) for possible options. Excerpt: `After the SQL Server Instance starts in single-user mode, the Windows Administrator account is able to connect to SQL Server using the sqlcmd utility using Windows authentication. You can use Transact-SQL commands such as "sp_addsrvrolemember" to add an existing login (or a newly created one) to the sysadmin server role.